# Netty-socketio exception listener

Tags: socket.io, netty

Does anyone know when is this handler executed in netty-socketio librairie ?

```java
    @Override
    public boolean exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable e) throws Exception {
        return false;
    }
```

The concerned class is here (the library is not well documented) : https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/blob/master/src/main/java/com/corundumstudio/socketio/listener/ExceptionListenerAdapter.java

Answer (score 0):

`exceptionCaught` event handler method is called when an exception was raised by Netty due to I/O error or by a handler implementation due to the exception thrown while processing events. In most cases, the caught exception should be logged and its associated channel should be closed here, although the implementation of this method can be different depending on what you want to do to deal with an exceptional situation. For example, you might want to send a response message with an error code before closing the connection.